# Does the DOM create an index on ids, classes, etc to improve querySelector performance?

Tags: javascript, dom

Does the DOM create an index on ids, classes, data attributes, etc to improve querySelector performance?  I would imagine this would cost resources at DOM load, but make querySelectors faster.

The alternative would be for it to traverse the DOM tree every time I make a call to querySelectorAll, which would improve render speed during the initial DOM construction, but at the cost of performance on DOM queries.

If you have a reference please share!

Comment: My assumption for ids and classes is yes.  Though I cannot point to documentation regarding that.  For data attributes, definitely not.

Comment: This was also my assumption.

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/

Comment: Ids and names must be stored in a map per specs (the global object being this map). Otherwise yes they "walk" the DOM tree at every call, that's why you should cache results, though it would be noticeable only on very large docs. To test these assertions you can go to single-page specs, like ECMA ones, and measure the time taken to find an element at the top of the doc vs at the bottom. getElementById takes always 0ms, querySelector(.foo) may take a few.